# Query if audio attachment AND/OR custom field

Tags: php, query, get-posts

I've been trying several things but to no avail... Searched, maybe not good enough though!

I have posts that either have an uploaded audio file AND/OR has a Soundcloud link (which is a custom field). I've built an audio player with Soundmanager that can play both.

Now I would like to return posts that either have a Soundcloud link, an uploaded file or both.

```
$arguments = array(              
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'audio',
    'order'          => 'DES',
    'orderby'        => 'parent',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
); 

$attachments = get_posts($args);
```

Is what I currently use. This of course, returns only posts that have an audio attachment.

I've been trying the `relation` and `meta_query` options, but failed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I think I could do this with 2 different `get_posts()` in an if/else statement. But I want to avoid repeating code.

Hope that is clear enough. Edit: to bump, I'm sorry. Edit 2:

If I add a Soundcloud link to the post when the post already has an audio attachment, the audio player will play the Soundcloud one. So that works, kinda. But I can't get it to work without an audio file. The Soundcloud link alone breaks it.

Comment: hmm. since you use 'post_mime_type' you automatically exclude all the other ones. why don't you use another custom field for your attachments and query for those..?

Comment: @honk31 Thanks for the reply. Well, this blog has a lot of old posts with attached audio files, that is why... I still haven't figured this out by the way.

Comment: maybe try to [merge two queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120367/10994)..? (i would build it with WP_Query, but looks promising (don't know, if that works, only saw the 'post_mime_type' argument in get_posts)) or go hard on sql query. should be possible, but since i never did it myself, i'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: @honk31 I'll try. I posted this also on Stack Overflow but someone said 2 queries was a bit too much, so I skipped that. I'll report back. If it works just make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: please go ahead and try around. post your progress here and lets see how this works out..