# How to support multiple search terms query within one process?

Tags: wp-query, filters, search

For **multiple** search terms; `?s=hello+world`

Wordpress work find **"hello world"** like `the_title` , `the_content` posts!

- *And, if our post title `Hello Anna` wordpress does not get one results!*

> I want to use all keys:
>
> **"hello world"** , **"hello"** , **"world"**

**Maybe**
`array('hello world','hello','world');` but it exceeds my exp.!
 Is it in a single loop may be able to divide the query and send multiple queries? Is there someone who can help on the subject? **e.g.** `?s=`, `$_GET`

> Wanted something must have been like to call more results for multiple queries!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed:
Search and result the all keys;

```
    <?php
        $the_keys = preg_split('/\s+/', str_replace('-',' ',get_query_var('s')),-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $total_keys = count($the_keys);

        $the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'nothing'));

        if($total_keys>1){

            for($i = 0; $i<=$total_keys; $i++) {
                $the_query_mask = new WP_Query(array('s' => $the_keys[$i]));
                $the_query->post_count = count( $the_query->posts );
                $the_query->posts = array_merge( $the_query->posts, $the_query_mask->posts );
            }               

        } else {

            $the_query= new WP_Query(array('s' => get_query_var('s')));

        }
        if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
```

Note: **`'post_type'=>'nothing'`** just need array merge!

Comment: it just needs to order the results by the default order after the array_merge

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is right. It is also necessary to mask some symbols. e.g. **How to ?** need to remove **?** key! But they're simple things. The hard part was solved. <3 wp

Comment: the other item that is missing is how the pagination would work (if you have any)

Comment: Performance versus value is the question and test you should be running. This may work well on a simple site, but a blog that posts daily, it's a large query, and this would be quite taxing in many cases. A better solution might be to limit query variables in the UI to begin with?

Comment: My solution would be an Ajax type search, where you add filters to single variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe somebody like me want **fuzzy logic results**

I solved this way: **"`search.php`"**

```
<?php
    $the_keys = preg_split('/\s+/', get_query_var('s'),-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    $total_keys = count($the_keys); // Count the search term

    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('s' => get_query_var('s')));

            // IF have multiple term and havent a result
            if($total_keys > 1 && $the_query->post_count < 1){

                // Loop for total term count, if found post break it! <3
                for($i = 0; $i < $total_keys; $i++) {

                    //Set the new array term value
                    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('s' => $the_keys[$i]));

                    //if found post break it! <3
                    if($the_query->post_count>0) break;

                }

            }
            // List of my Level 2 filter posts :)
            if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>

......

<?php 
endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

---

### **e.g.** post title: ( **Hello baby** )

Normaly:

- `?s=hello+baby` => **find true**
- `?s=hello` => **find true**
- `?s=baby` => **find true**
- `?s=hello+whats+up` => **find false**
- `?s=hey+baby` => **find false**

search, Work now and find **e.g.** `?s=hello+whats+up` => **find true**

Comment: I think replace the result message: e.g. " **hello what's up** not found, List of **hello** "  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71576/combining-queries-with-different-arguments-per-post-type

Comment: I don't like how it breaks the search when it finds results with one key and not return results for all keys though

Comment: Hi, @juz please you examine it?http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/223737/84842

Answer (score -1):

You are getting into deep water quickly. I would look into SearchWP plugin as they provide LIKE searching and Fuzzy matching. [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com/)

Comment: Thank you @1Bladesforhire 
I know this logic, but exhaustive for servers! Plug-in create a term cloud. It not suitable for the size of the project.

Comment: I work on the `$query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => 'keyword' ) );` `'s' => array('keyword','keyword')` but i need help.

Comment: @HybridWebDev no affiliation, just have used the plugin and liked it. Has the needed stuff and thought I would offer it as an alternative.